# How to reload a table from another class? - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, class, nstableview

I've been trying to do this for a while, I have a tableViewController class and my AppDelegate class and the tableViewController class is the datasource for the table obviously. But I want the table to load on startup and I can't figure out any other way to do this than call the table loading method from the tableViewController class in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the AppDelegate. But this seems to not work. Nothing happens, just a blank table.

This is the loading method from the tableViewController:

```
-(void)loadTable {
NSString* path = [@"~/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
self.list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

And this is where I'm calling it from the AppDelegate

```
#import "tableViewController.h"
//other code

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    tableViewController *tableClass = [[tableViewController alloc] init];
    [tableClass loadTable];
}
```

I still can't figure out why this isn't working. And if this is not the right way to do this please tell me.

Comment: looks like a long term relationship *lol*

What are you using as data for your table? An array? A database? Core Data? The later would be the most convenient, if you did not have any non-standard objects in your data pool.

For basic table stuff, try:

http://www.cocoa-coding.de/todo/todo.html

Unfortunately, that one is in German, but looking at the code and the images might give you some direction.

For core data, give this article a try:

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php

In general: get more detailed and we can help!

Cheers,

Living

Comment: Well right now I'm using the NSTableViewDataSource protocol and the tableViewController class is the table view's datasource. BUT I can't seem to call the reloading method from another class, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

**Datasource**

Create new implementation & interface which inherits from `NSObject` and conforms to `NSTableViewDataSource`.

`Datasource` must implement three methods:

`- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView;`

`- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView 
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn 
            row:(int)rowIndex;`

`- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
   setObjectValue:(id)anObject
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
              row:(int)rowIndex;`

You can read about those methods in [NSTableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

**TableView**

In `- (void)awakeFromNib` method set datasource `[self setDataSource:datasource];` and  reload table data`[self reloadData];`

I hope it'll help you !

Comment: Ok well I'm already using these methods in the tableViewController class but I can't reload it from the AppDelegate so...